# Why Inheritance is one of the four major principles of OOP, but not Composition?

Tags: oop, inheritance, composition

How **Composition** is a lesser principle level, than **Inheritance**? One always has to consider **Composition** over **Inheritance**, but there is no mention of **Composition** in the four major OOP principles. What is the reason behind this? Are they not at the same level?

Comment: Although composition is a way to do things, it is not a concept introduced by OOP. Composition is a result of the OOP principles (having an object).

Comment: Yes, the same level of importance/relevance. But OOP doesn't really depend on it nor does composition really depend on OOP. They just go together very well..

Comment: OOP relies heavily on composition > without composition no complex data types or object associations. Composition is a prerequisite to OOP design principles.

Comment: Composition has been around since before OOP. Also, there are no levels.

Comment: The "four major principles" are of debateable utility when talking about object orientation. The inventor of the concept said that OO involved only "message passing and extreme late binding". No mention of the four principles. An OO language can be envisaged that does not have inheritance. At its heart your question is "why is this human concept as it is?". The answer has to be that it was an emergent grouping of concepts that people found useful when discussing OO.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah, the tag is pointless but the question is interesting

Comment: Composition is about using parts to build a whole. Inheritance is about reusing code. The former is a sensible way to construct things, the latter results in a leaning tower of complexity and dependency.

Answer (score 2):

**Composition** is a lower-level and a much older concept than **inheritance**; it comes from the **analysis-synthesis approach** which basically states that things are either composed of other things or trivial (atomic). It was first introduced back in ancient Greece as a general approach to understanding things.

**Composition** is not specific to OOP, e.g. in plain C, which is far from being OO, structs are authored using composition, likewise in functional programming functions are **composed of** other functions, though the nature of **composition** is totally different in these two examples.